# Create a report showing a few specific artifacts

Tags: tuleap

I need to create a report showing some specific artifacts. There is not any way to search for them, except knowing their IDs. Is there any way I can create a report for them?

Let say I want a report showing artifacts IDs 1, 7 and 13. How can I create such a report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have not found any answer to this specific need, I have created Python package to get this feature.
It is available here: https://gitlab.com/Simpom/tare

Thanks to this package, the solution to the specific question is:

```
from tare import Tuleap
tuleap = Tuleap('https://my_tuleap_server.com/plugins/tracker/?tracker=12')
report = tuleap.get_report([1, 7, 13])
print(report.summary())
```